# Unable to update the value outside and inside the function

Tags: jquery

After multiples time trying I'm failed to update the values from both outside the function and inside the function. The problem is the variable values inside the function is not accessable out side the function and unable to update  variable value inside the function.My [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/innoo_devil/77zz2a10/) is here .

My code is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table class="invtable table table-bordered table-hover" >
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th class="col-md-1" >No.</th>

                <th class="col-md-2">ProductName</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Qty</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Price</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">PDis</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">TDis</th>
                <th class="col-md-3">Amount</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">X</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>







            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="details">
        <tr >
                <td class= count ></td>
                <td ><input type="text" name="product_name[]" value="ABC" class="form-control product_name" readonly >
                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" name="quantity[]" value="1" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" name="price[]" value="5" class="form-control price" ></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.01"  name="discount[]" value="0" class="form-control discount" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.01"  name="tdiscount[]" value="0" class="form-control tdiscount" autocomplete="off"></td>
                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" readonly></td>
                </tr>



</body>
</html>
<script>
$(function(){
            $('body').on('keyup','.discount,.tdiscount,.quantity,.price',function(){

                var tr      =   $(this).parent().parent();  
                var dis     =   tr.find('.discount').val();
                var tdis    =   tr.find('.tdiscount').val();
                var qty     =   tr.find('.quantity').val();
                var price   =   tr.find('.price').val();

                total   = (qty*price) -(0);

            $('.tdiscount').keyup(function(){
                alert(total);
                total   = (qty*price) -(tdis);
                alert(total);       
                dis = (tdis/qty);
                //tr.find('.discount').val(tdis/qty);   
        });

                tr.find('.amount').val(total);
            });


});
</script>
```

All I want is as I give some value to Tdis than it will update the AMOUNT textbox after deduction of Tdis value and Tdis divided by the given QTY and  also update values goes into the Pdis textbox.
But I'm not succeeded , morever, if I used this piece of code...

```
$('.tdiscount').keyup(function(){               
  total = (qty*price) -(tdis);              
  tr.find('.discount').val(tdis/qty);       
});
```

Than it will need twice the **KEYPRESS** inside the Tdis to update Pdis textbox, kindly clear my that confusion , why it need twice time keypress to update that value and how can I prevent to press twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your second keyup event and you should be all set.  You can also use "input" as your selector instead of specifying each class to make it simpler.

```
$(function(){
        $('input').on('keyup', function(){

            var tr      =   $(this).parent().parent();  
            var dis     =   tr.find('.discount').val();
            var tdis    =   tr.find('.tdiscount').val();
            var qty     =   tr.find('.quantity').val();
            var price   =   tr.find('.price').val();

            total   = (qty*price) -(0);

            total   = (qty*price) -(tdis);
            alert(total);       
            dis = (tdis/qty);

            tr.find('.amount').val(total);
        });
});
```

Comment: still facing the same issue "dis" is not updated in textbox while updated in alertbox.

Comment: Here's a hint:  You are populating `.amount` with the variable `total` which is currently set to:  `(qty * price) - (tdis);`